# Angular : Can't access injected dependency constant

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, webpack

I'm using Webpack 1.13.2 with Angular 1.5.8 and I can't manage to access my "SETTINGS" constant from my poiService file.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'API_URL' of undefined

http://plnkr.co/edit/6repllAk39kv4Enfw8RU?p=catalogue
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PoiService` has mismatching annotation:

```
services.factory('PoiService', ['SETTINGS', require('./poiService')])
```

service definition and

```
module.exports = function ($http, SETTINGS) { ... }
```

function signature.

For this reason it may be not advisable to keep factory function and service definition in separate files. And even if there's a need to do this, it is preferable to use named function and `$inject` annotation instead of inline array annotation:

```
services.factory('PoiService', require('./poiService'))

...

poiService.$inject = ['$http', 'SETTINGS'];
function poiService($http, SETTINGS) { ... }
module.exports = poiService;
```

Comment: Could you show me how you'd do it with inline array annotation please ?

Comment: `services.factory('PoiService', ['$http', 'SETTINGS', require('./poiService')])`. As said, there is a mismatch. Two items are expected to be injected, two items should be annotated in the same order. And the possible cause of this is that you don't see DI annotation and function signature simultaneously with coding style like that.

Comment: Is there any point of doing `module.exports = poiService instead of module.exports = function($http, SETTINGS) { }` ? Assuming the poiService file only contains the poiService definition and nothing else ? Thanks a lot by the way !

Comment: It is not necessary if inline array annotation is used. There is a reason to use named function if `$inject` annotation is used. Check also [JP style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) for more details on the subject.

Comment: Is there any difference (performance, anything) in the way it's defined in controller 1 and 2 ? http://plnkr.co/edit/v2Kn7acOSTK3QYOOvPyt?p=catalogue @estus

Comment: @adaba No. One of them uses [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting), an essential JS feature. These two cases are identical. There may be differences in performance due to browser quirks, but generally the performance is considered the same.